# Can I get explanation for (1 + undefined) implicitly Coercion weird behavior in JS?

Tags: javascript, coercion, type-coercion

I understand the implicit coercion that happens in javascript, but i actually can't understand why this happens:

```
isNaN(1 + null)      // false
isNaN(1 + undefined) // true
```

As i know that JS convert the null & undefined to 0, Or we could say consider them false value.

***what is the difference here ?***

Answer (score 3):

Javascript converts `null` to 0 but `undefined` is converted to `NaN`.
check it out using the built in fucntion `Number` .
So in this case `(1+ null)` is similar to `1+ 0` which is `1`
and `(1+ undefined)` is similar `1 + NaN` which is `NaN`.

**That's why it returns true.**

```js
console.log(Number(null));
console.log(Number(undefined));
```

The weird behavior here though is that Javascript consider both of these types "false" when dealing with comparison operator or as a condition in if statement and false value considered 0 after implicitly coerced...

***Conclusion***: Js coerce `undefined & null` depending on the situation. if it's in condition, it try to convert it to boolean `false` & if it's in an arithmetic operation it try to convert it to numbers, in this case there would be difference between them:

> undefined ==> NaN
>
> null ==> 0

Comment: It‘s certainly right that values are coerced differently depending on context. If you do `if(x)` then the value of `x` is converted to a boolean. `a + b` with either being a number expects the other one to be a number. Similarly if one is a string the other will be converted to a string.

Comment: @connexo Probably to share the knowledge with the world. [Self-answers are fine and actually encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: it's okay to answer your own question in stack @connexo